# Prevent CollapsingToolBarLayout from expanding programmatically

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using a CollapsingToolBarLayout in my main activity, but only want it to be expandable in some fragments. To do this, I've been using these methods(right after fragment transactions/detatch). These successfully animate the toolbar, but it is still expandable in fragments that have called lockAppBarClosed.

```
public void unlockAppBarOpen(boolean animate){
    appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, animate);
    appBarLayout.setEnabled(true);
    appBarLayout.setActivated(true);
}
public void lockAppBarClosed(boolean animate){
    appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, animate);
    appBarLayout.setEnabled(false);
    appBarLayout.setActivated(false);
}
```

`setEnabled` and `setActivated` seem to do nothing.

For reference, here is my app_bar_main.xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_extended"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</FrameLayout>
```

I've tried setting the height of the AppBarLayout via LayoutParams(), but this, for some reason, prevents the animation from playing, even when `animate` is set to true. Setting the scroll flags to none or `always collapsed` does nothing, and I'm not looking for the scroll `snap` effect either.

Ideally, there should be no animation of the appbar in one fragment(just like normal), and collapsing/expanding animations when going between fragments and in desired ones.

If you have any suggestions, they would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(true)` to expand Toolbar and use `mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(false)` to collapse **Toolbar** programmatically.

> If you want to prevent **CollapsingToolbarLayout** from expanding then you should use `mAppBarLayout.setLayoutParams(params)` to change
>   `CollapsingToolbarLayout` height programmatically.

**Collapse:**

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params =(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mAppBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 3*80; // COLLAPSED_HEIGHT

mAppBarLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
```

**Expand:**

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mAppBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 3*200; // EXPANDED_HEIGHT

mAppBarLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
```

Hope this will help you~

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a CollapsingToolBarLayout in the activity_main.xml,I would suggest you to use an actionbar or normal toolbar in your main activity itself where as in those specific fragments, where you want to access CollapsingToolBarLayout, add it in the xml file of the fragment like below:

```
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/specific_coordinate"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"

                    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                    <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp">
            </ImageView>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarLayoutExpandedTextStyle"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >

                    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <include layout="@layout/specific_content" />

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>





        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

    where the specific_content.xml is an xml file that carries the fragment contents.

    In the fragment code where you want the CollapsingToolBarLayout, disable the MainActivity actionbar/toolbar and you can see the CollapsingToolBarLayout there. Hope that will help. Happy coding.
```